# Running Visual Studio on a web server where IIS is running

Tags: visual-studio

I have a web application that I am developing in Visual Studio 2019.  I am able to launch the application on my development machine where I have IIS express installed. When I launch the application from within Visual Studio, I click on the button which says “Chrome (express)”.

The application runs fine on my development machine, making use of IBM web sphere mq messaging.

When I push my application to the server, the application fails to connect to the mq messages handler.

So, I need to run Visual studio on the server so I can set break points and debug the application.

How can I change the Visual Studio debugging environment to it makes use of IIS and not IIS express?